# Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Tags: java, hashmap

I've the code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>;
```

Now in Eclipse is `new HashMap<String, String>` red underlined.

```
The Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

What does it mean and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a ()! `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`

With **new HashMap**, you call the `HashMap.java`. To initialize the HashMap, you should call the Constructer. Here with ().

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); //<-- add parentheses
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some brackets:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```